# Something is wrong with my hdri

Tags: hdri

I'm not sure how to describe it with words but when I add my hdri it looks completely messed up. Anyone who knows what's going on and how to fix it?

In blender:

[image]

How it's supposed to look:

[image]

(Old link - https://i.stack.imgur.com/juij7.jpg)

Comment: Hi :). Are you sure you're using the *Environment Texture* node? It's needed to display HDRIs correctly.

Comment: This is not a correct HDRI image

Answer (score 2):

That image appears to be from HDRI Skys: [HDRI Sky 363](https://hdri-skies.com/hdri-skies/hdri-sky-363/)  but it's not the actual HDRI, it's a screenshot of a portion of the HDRI rendered (some versions of such screenshots are called a [backplate](https://www.domeble.com/backplates/)).  You need to select the free download (see image) and unpack the zip file that it downloads.

[image: image showing the free download button.]

In the zip file you will find a file called *363-free-hdri-skies-com.hdr*.  Put that somewhere and then make sure your world shader looks like this:

[image: World shader]

and that you have the hdr file selected in the *Image Texture*.  Here's a partial view from my Blender showing the result of doing that:

[image: part of the HDRI background.]

Answer (score 1):

If the picture you show is supposed to be your HDRI, it is not a correct HDRI. An HDRI is a 360° image (from left to right but also from bottom to top) that can be projected on a sphere (your world will be like a sphere around your scene), see the difference between your image and a correct HDRI:

[image]

See what your image gives compared to a correct HDRI:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not enough reputation yet to comment, but like others said, you need to have a real hdri. PolyHaven has hundreds of free hdris. Try it out!

https://polyhaven.com/hdris